# How to determine when the nth element has been added to reload the table view row in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UICollectionView`. In the `UICollectionView`, each "row" can fit a total of 4 `UIImages`. I'm having a bit of a difficult time figuring out the logic behind how to determine when the nth element is added to produce the "next" row so I can reload the table view row to expand its `UITableViewCell` height.

For example, here's how the first row in the `UITableViewCell` looks like with 4 images:

```
[ x x x x]
```

In my code, when the 5th image is added, the `UITableViewCell`'s height expands to fit the additional 5th image:

```
[ x x x x]
[ 5      ]
```

It continues on with the 5th, 9th, 13th, 17th, etc. image that I would like to check before reloading the table view row to expand the height of the `UITableViewCell` to fit the next set of images.

The images are added to an array and currently I'm doing something like this:

```
if (images.count % 5) == 0
{
    self.imagesTableView.reloadRows(at: [ IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4) ],
                                            with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
}
```

Obviously, the logic only works when it is a multiple of 5. I feel like it's a simple logic check, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct condition for your case is

```
let isMultiple = ((i-1) % n) == 0
```

Or

```
let isMultiple = (i % n) == 1
```

An idea of implementation would be something like:

```
let itemsPerRow = 4
let filter = { (itemNumber: Int) -> Bool in
    return (itemNumber > itemsPerRow) && ((itemNumber % itemsPerRow) == 1)
}
print(Array(1...20).filter(filter))
// prints [5, 9, 13, 17]
```

Comment: `let isMultiple = ((i-1) % n) == 0` was definitely the logic I needed...so simple can't believe I couldn't figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

I might be totally missing the point of your question but...

I think it should be:

```
if (images.count % 4) == 1
{
    self.imagesTableView.reloadRows(at: [ IndexPath(row: 0, section: 4) ],
                                            with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
}
```

If you want you can also check that (images.count > 5) in case there's a problem with the code running on the first  added image.

Comment: I want to be able to enter that if check whenever images.count = 5, (5) + 4, (5 +4) + 4, (5 + 4 +4) + 4, etc., therefore your code answer does not solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're going to want something along the lines of this:

```
let previousCount = self.images.count
self.images.append(newElement) // This is where you are updating your images array

let previousNumberOfRows = (previousCount / 4) + 1 // May want to explicitly check the case where previousCount == 0 if you don't want any rows to show for that case
let updatedNumberOfRows = (self.images.count / 4) + 1 // Again, may want to handle 0 items case
let rowDiff = updatedNumberOfRows - previousNumberOfRows

guard rowDiff != 0 else {
  return
}

let range: CountableRange
if rowDiff > 0 {
  range = (0 ..< rowDiff)
} else {
  range = (rowDiff ..< 0)
}

let indexPathsToReload = range.flatMap { sectionIndex in 
    return IndexPath(row: sectionIndex + previousNumberOfSections, section: 0)
}
self.imagesTableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathsToReload)
```

I had to type this answer quickly so there's potentially an off-by-one error. Let me know how it goes!